# ActiveReports 7 - Does an application license expire? If so, when?

Tags: c#, dll, licensing, activereports

On a project that the team I am on is nearly done with, we've had seemingly intermittent `Access is Denied` errors on our Test environment, stemming from our assembly's ActiveReports License DLL.

After spending many, *many* manhours, we were able to determine a pattern: we would build our project to the Test environment, where our app would work just fine for that day.  *However*, the next day any attempt to view a report would meet with an `Access Denied` violation.

As a test, we built our project in Test, and waited one day.  Sure enough, we started seeing errors.  However, we immediately re-generated our License DLL for the assembly, and plugged it in - this caused our `Access is Denied` errors to *vanish.*

The suspicion on our team is that this may point to some sort of 'active period' on the license, as if our Assembly License DLL was being treated as a 1-day trial license of some description.

**Question:** Under what circumstances does an ActiveReports License DLL have a 1-day limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you have a paid license.

We have not seen an error like this and there is no 1-day limit as such.  If the license is paid, there is no "time" limit. It is valid for ever. Only trial license has 30-days time limit and that will come with a nag screen in Visual Studio and the pages have an eval message at the bottom after report is run.

What do you mean by "However, we immediately re-generated our License DLL for the assembly"?  You say that error is seen when you view the report. So, the project compiles just fine, but the license info does not get embedded.  Am I correct?

We have a license diagnostic tool that we use sometime to troubleshoot these scenarios.